# How can I handle timeout errors in MongoClient?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am connecting a nodejs app to my mongodb database using the following:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs'
let client = new MongoClient(url, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 60000,    
  socketTimeoutMS: 60000, 
 })
try {
  let dbclient = await client.connect()
  console.log(dbclient)
  const db = dbclient.db('test')
  const collection = db.collection('accounts')
  const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline)
  changeStream.on("change", function(change) {
    console.log('changed', change)
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('mongo err:', err)
}
```

This works perfectly, however it regularly loses connection after a few minutes with the error:

> Uncaught MongoNetworkError: connection 6 to localhost:27017 timed out

According to [the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/) it should automatically reconnect up to 30 tries upon error, however it does not appear to make any further attempts to reconnect.

I will also need to run some additional logic on reconnect to properly handle local state.

How can I catch and handle these errors?

Edit: While I'm still not getting other events, I am getting 'reconnect' events after the errors occur. So it seems I can at least react to the errors, but still not actually catch them.

Comment: Just add to the connection  `keepAlive: true,` or specific time `keepAlive: 300000`

Comment: Setting it to `true` seems to do the trick, thanks!

Comment: I  will add it as answer. Maybe someone will find it helpful.

Comment: Have you tried setting `bufferMaxEntries:0` so the operation fails as soon you are disconnected ?

Comment: @Thebluefish any luck?

Answer (score 4):

Just add to the connection `keepAlive: true`, or specific time `keepAlive: 300000`

See the example here:https://ide.c9.io/ibrahimth/mongo

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs'
// Database Name
const dbName = 'test';

// create a client, passing in additional options
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
   keepAlive: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 60000,    
  socketTimeoutMS: 60000, 
});

// Use connect method to connect to the server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
const db = client.db(dbName);
createCollated(db, function() {
    client.close();
  });


});


function createCollated(db, callback) {
  db.createCollection('acount',
    {
      'collation' :
        { 'acountnam': 'firstacount' }
    },

    function(err, results) {
      console.log("Collection created.");
      callback();
    }
  );
};
```

For more information: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/collations/

Comment: Actually finally ran into the issue again today, using this fix. Interestingly the error I received now is slightly different, with the error wrapped in an object (keys: name, message, stack) than just a plain message. Still not finding a way to catch it, though.

Comment: @Thebluefish try to do this `socketTimeoutMS: 3000000,`
            `connectionTimeoutMS: 3000000,`
            `keepAlive:3000000`

Comment: I don't think increasing the existing timeout is going to help me handle these errors as they come up. They may cause them to happen less often, but I need to actually *properly* handle them when they happen.

Comment: @Thebluefish I found this it may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688282/handling-timeouts-with-node-js-and-mongodb

Comment: I've tried listening to 'close' and 'error' events on just about everything I can think of related to the connection, however none of them seem to ever get hit.

Comment: @Thebluefish try to remove `useNewUrlParser: true,` and put `socketTimeoutMS: 3000000, connectionTimeoutMS: 3000000, keepAlive:3000000`

Comment: I'm very confused how collations will help me handle this error that's appearing. The example code still produces the occasional error upon testing.

Comment: @Thebluefish It works fine but I noticed your comment and I look for an answer and I found that the problem may appear in specific mongo version see this:https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4789. So, try to downgrade your version or upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 var mongo = {};
 mongo.init = function() {
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db',function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Err',err);
    } else {
      mongo.DB = db;
    }
    db.on('reconnect', function() {
      mongo.DB = db;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Handling the `reconnect` event doesn't help handling the error itself. Also, I am unsure how to properly handle the change stream in this case. When the `reconnect` event fires and no error occurs, the change stream still receives events. However when the event fires after an error, it does not. I am not finding a good way to distinguish between the two when handling the `reconnect` event. Ideally, I wish to handle the actual error itself.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you add `reconnectTries` which acts as *Server attempt to reconnect #times*, and add other options which should stabilize your connection, then you modify your codes back to:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs'
let client = new MongoClient(url, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  connectTimeoutMS: 30000,    
  socketTimeoutMS:  360000, 
  useMongoClient: true,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: 30
 })
try {
  let dbclient = await client.connect()
  console.log(dbclient)
  const db = dbclient.db('test')
  const collection = db.collection('accounts')
  const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline)
  changeStream.on("change", function(change) {
    console.log('changed', change)
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('mongo err:', err)
}
```